# What is the word used to describe things ordered by height?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I’m wondering if there is a word used for using height to order something. Just like we say alphabetical order for things arranged by their spelling, or chronological order for things arranged by their dates, is there an *x* order, where *x* refers to things arranged by height?

I want to be able to say, “In the picture where the kids are in *x* order…”

I’m not sure how to look this up in a dictionary but have tried google, without any success. I also checked Merriam-Webster‘s thesaurus without any luck. (Pinnacle order? That doesn’t sound right.)

I expect the word I want would probably end in “-cal” but I guess it might not necessarily. I’m not sure the Latin or Greek behind the “-cal” in alphabetical and chronological.

Comment: The kids are in order of height, perhaps. But isn’t this obvious to the viewer?

Comment: I am curious about the motive for wanting to say it with an adjective ending in **-ical** when that is obviously not how it is said by everyone, for if it were, you would already know the word. What end is achieved by using an obscure word?

Comment: You could look up collocating premodifiers of 'order' in a collocations dictionary. 'Alphabetical' and 'numerical' are two strong collocates.

Comment: How are you defining **height**? Is "height" the person's physical "tallness" as measured when standing  (outside the photo context) or is it the elevation of the head in the photo-space? What if a taller kid is seated, and a shorter sibling's head is at a higher height in the photo than the taller's head?

Comment: @TimR Sometimes among a small group of certain specific friends it’s fun for us to use very specific words and thereby learn something together. I also thought it was possible there was a regular well-used word for this I just wasn’t thinking of.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks for this, I never knew about a collocations dictionary until today.

Comment: @Tim good questions, I’m not sure I had even considered these.

Comment: @Fivestones: I suppose *specificity for the sake of specificity* is OK. But if you want a very specific word you need to provide a very specific example showing how you intend to use it; the language of the example should be in the same register as the word you're looking for.  It can't be something like *Yo' mama wears [word for military-style boots with a waterproof inner lining, brass grommets, and a carbon fiber arch support].* Also, looking for words to name a program function or an object property would not be a question about *natural* language, IMO, but about programming conventions.

Comment: I can't believe everyone missed it, higherarchical :)

Comment: Since "a tall man" in Latin is *homo longus*, the proper word should be "longitudinally", but modern usage lets us think of geographic locations...

Comment: @JoshuaJurgensmeier heh, that's a good one! I also like "ascending/descending order"

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use **height** itself. It can serve as a noun adjunct in the noun phrase *height order*.

> In the picture where the kids are in height order...

---

*Hypsometrical* is a scientific term with the meaning "relating to the measurement of altitudes/heights" and comes from a Greek root like *chronological*. However, it is only used in technical contexts mainly related to altitudes and elevations; and it won't work in colloquial speech, thus it can't be used in your context.

> Hypsometric is a scientific term relating to the measurement of heights. The term originates from the Greek word ὕψος "hypsos" meaning height and the word *metre* is from the Greek μέτρον (*métron*), "a measure"
>
> [*Wikipedia*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypsometric)

Comment: "in height order" is how my teachers always used to tell us to line up. I'm not sure *why* we needed to do it that way, but it was pretty common.

Comment: This really doesn't sound right, given that height is a noun and not an adjective.

Comment: "in height order" sounds perfectly idiomatic to my British English ear - more so than any of the other options here

Comment: I think this answer would be better if it dropped the stuff about *hypsometrical* entirely. As the answer itself states, no one would use the word in regard to the ordering of a line up of children in a photograph.

Comment: I think mentioning _hypsometrical_ makes it even better answer. It is just a bonus part with a relevant explanation coming after the actual answer that works. The OP was wondering about possible words ending with *-cal* like *chronological* in the question.

Comment: This answer is great. I appreciated all the answers I’m reading here, 7 of them so far, but this hits the nail on the head. Both with *hypsometrical* and with *height order*. Hypsometrical is exactly the word I was hoping existed and was looking for (sometimes a person wants to use a technical word in a colloquial context among specific friends who know and understand that person because it’s the exact word for the job even if none of them has ever heard of it before), and height order is the obvious thing to use in regular conversation. Thank you!

Comment: @Barmar Was it picture day? It's so the photographer only has to adjust the seat in one direction

Comment: @Barmar, That might be so the teacher could then select teams equalizing heights of players - TeamA being the even ones and TeamB the odd (more accurately ends towards the middle).

Comment: @civitas It's been a long time, but I think it was when we were lining up to go to lunch, fire drills, or to get on the bus for a field trip.

Comment: *Height order* is not idiomatic in my form of American English. *Order of height* would be way more natural.

Answer (score 22):

You could say that you are ordering them **heightwise.** [Wiktionary defines this as:](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/heightwise)

> In terms of height; vertical.

Comment: That's a good, useful English suffix with many [uses](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-wise).

Answer (score 9):

Just adding another *idiomatic* possibility to the list:

> ... arranged **by height**

Comment: OP uses this in the title. I'm not sure why they need an alternative.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth And I'm not sure why they needed to go looking for an obscure word when they already have a perfectly idiomatic expression at their fingertips. With this answer I'm gently chastising OP for not providing a rationale or context to justify the question. Besides, OP is in the long run irrelevant, as this answer will outlive their immediate need, and we wouldn't want to create the impression for some unsuspecting language learner that the obscure word, if one ever turns up, is as suitable as or more suitable than the tried-and-true, absent a specific description of the need.

Comment: @TimR but don’t forget about all the native English speakers like me who also like me want to have the very specific word for the job even if it’s not the most idiomatic English. Why have all these great words like *hypsometrical* if they don’t get used?  I’m very gently pushing back on your gentle chastising since I’m probably a very different person in my usage of English than you are—and that’s ok, and that’s why I asked this question 

Comment: Why did the chicken cross the road?   -- To hear somebody using big words nobody knows.

Comment: @TimR didn't it cross the road to effect a traversal? 

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the OP could be more specific as to which items (or organisms) they want to be ordered by height?

**[Ascending](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ascending)** (from “shortest” to “tallest”) could work.
It's often associated by size or price rather than by height but if the context is quickly established who would *raise* an eyebrow? Alternatively, the phrase “ascending order of height” is the least equivocal.

*[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20ascending%20order)* offers this example of usage

> **The children were lined up in ascending order of height.**

Just for the record, here are the most common file classifications, in alphabetical order:

- alphabetical order
- [alphanumeric](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/alphanumeric) order
- chronological order
- numerical order

Comment: Ascending height (except for Kevin who doesn't follow directions well)

Comment: I actually like this a lot. Thanks

Comment: And if your going the other way, it's descending order

Comment: @aslum, I usually wore the dunce cap, on or off?

Answer (score 2):

Statural order is a word that could be used.

[Of or relating to stature](https://premium-oxforddictionaries-com.libproxy.ucl.ac.uk/definition/english/statural)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Interesting find. Although, it is a term used in biology, usually as in the phrase "statural growth". A phrase like "statural order" is not used and it won't work in colloquial speech. Perhaps you can add these details and add a definition of "stature".

Comment: Stature is definitely not the usual word for the height of a person. The usual word is height, which is very commonly used attributively (as in "height order").

Comment: @StuartF It appears that the OP wants the ability to sort things by height, as if placing an order `“if there is a word used for using height to order something“` Structural order is a possibility, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You could say **tallest first**, **shortest last**, **shortest to tallest**, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

When I was in elementary school, we were told to line up in "size places," meaning single file with shortest in front and tallest at rear. 1950s New York City

Answer (score -3):

You could use "vertical".  As in "I've arranged the children in vertical order".  I wouldn't call it common phrasing but I believe it would be well understood.  In most cases I think common phrasing would be "in order of height".

**Update**

I'm surprised people are confusing the idea of a "stack" and "vertical".  Stack can mean many things some connected with the notion of the vertical, some not.  You can stack horizontally or call a random pile a stack.  When I see vertical, I think perpendicular to the horizonal, upright, directly overhead, *height*.  "He had me at a vertical advantage", is often a dole way to reference a height difference.  The context stresses the difference not the reason for the difference.  Perhaps one is a giant, or perhaps a child is "stacked" on the shoulders of a parent.  In the SO's question the context was a picture, it seems difficult for me to think people would misunderstand the concept of "vertical" if they saw the children side by side and not "stacked".  Granted, I tend to think more mathematically than most.

I still say the common phrasing is "in order of height", (or in "height order").  I'm impressed with Hypsometrical, but as noted "it won't work in colloquial speech" (i.e., you won't be commonly understood).  Still, it's a great word :-).

That said it appears the concept of vertical isn't well understood either, but in the context of a picture I suspect *many* people would understand it.  Given the confusion my suggestion generated, it's likely a bad choice unless you understand your target audience well.

Comment: Doesn't that imply that the kids are stacked on top of one another?

Comment: Three other people seem to think so, but I can't imagine why.  The word "stack" means that.  Vertical simply implies a direction, or height.  Sometimes it's used in the context of a hierarchy, but even there it implies "up-down", not stacked.  Are you suggesting that a sentence like "The drunken men raised themselves from the horizontal to the vertical" implies the men were laying in a line and then formed a human pyramid?

Comment: For me, I think the issue is that while the tops of their heads may be displaced vertically, there's also horizontal distance too. And there's a lot more than just the tops of their heads: the majority of their bodies will overlap heightwise, so the vertical ordering is a lot less clear. (For example, the heights of their navels may not be in the same order.)

Comment: But *vertical* refers to orientation not extent.  Using it to describe the ordering of people in a line up suggests that the people are arranged by the angle their major axis subtends with the horizontal.  A perfectly feasible arrangement, but not one that agrees with an arrangement by their heights.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I love your comment, it mades me immediately think of a new "collection" word ... a vertical of drunkards :-)  ... I don't disagree, with the specific definition, but the word is used in broader contexts.  I can see how an immediate connection with height might be confused in a text only description, but generally understood when associated with a picture (as was the OP's question).  The word itself makes me thing "angle" but within that context I would understand 'height'.  If I say "vertical cliff" the brain thinks "high", but the words don't explicitly imply that.

Comment: I love this answer, especially the details you added in the update. I agree completely. I also was impressed with *hypsometrical* and gave it the answer checkmark as it was just was I was looking for. But thanks for *vertical* and your defense of it.

Comment: @Dweeberly vertical of drunkards is a pretty great collective noun usage

Comment: This is just not idiomatic. Google "vertical order" and all the results relate to things that move up-down instead of left-right (lists, traversals, warehouse pickers, etc...)

Comment: If someone said "in vertical order" to me, and I happened to understand what they meant (not a given), my first thought would be that "vertical" was the wrong word.